# Action bar title shows unnecessary transition in font family

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-fonts

Use the link to see the video -> https://kapwi.ng/c/Mxr9xB7e

The font style in title of action bar shows undesired font family at first and then shows the font family mentioned in app style. This happens only in MainActivty. You can see that around 1 sec time in video.

I tried many things like programmatically changing font family of getSupportActionBar(). I also used overridePendingTransition() but nothing works.

The problem only happens in MainActivity. MainActivtiy consist of a ViewPager and TabLayout. The fragment which first loads consist of YouTubePlayerFragment and a recyclerView fetching data from Firebase database.

Below are the images:

Image 1 is of DBCheckActivity which shows correct font mentioned in style. Image 2 is of MainActivity that shows incorrect font family of title in ActionBar and then transitions to correct font family in Image 3. MainActivity is launched from DBCheckActivity.

[image: DBCheckActivity]
[image: MainActivity with undesired font of title]
[image: MainActivity shows later desired font]

Below is the App theme style code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/acme</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>
```

Could anyone tell what possibly may be causing this problem and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

try to check androidmanifest are DBCheckActivity is use the themes

```
<activity android:name=".DBCheckActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```